# How to create a .NET Maui IAppIndexingProvider concrete implementation?

Tags: deep-linking, maui

I am attempting to implement deep linking in my Maui app and register a link entry in the App.xaml.cs constructor:

```
 var entry = new AppLinkEntry
 {
     Title = "Find Shop",
     Description = "Find Shop Deep Link",
     AppLinkUri = new Uri(GlobalVariables.FindShopDeepLink, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
     IsLinkActive = true,
     Thumbnail = ImageSource.FromFile("popupshop_purple.png")
  };

  entry.KeyValues.Add("contentType", "id");
  entry.KeyValues.Add("appName", "PopUp Shop");
  entry.KeyValues.Add("companyName", "Cefworx, LLC");

  Application.Current.AppLinks.RegisterLink(entry);
```

This gets the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: No IAppIndexingProvider was provided
```

I was thinking maybe I need to create the provider and pass it through:

```
this.SetAppIndexingProvider(new AppIndexingProvider());
```

but that is not a valid concrete implementation  of the IAppIndexingProvider interface and I can't find any info on what is a valid indexing provider.

Comment: Maui doc for SetAppIndexingprovider says *"For internal use by the Microsoft.Maui.Controls platform"*. Its Maui's responsibility to provide this, not the app. Likely related to [this Maui Applinks issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12295).  Currently on BackLog; seems that no one has investigated it yet. I don't know whether there is any workaround. There is a mention in that issue of `entitlements.plist`; you might search for any other discussion of entitlements and deep linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the comment thread about [AppLinks in iOS return "No IAppIndexingProvider"](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12295).

You can try to add the code to the App.cs file.

```
#if IOS
(Application.Current as IApplicationController)?.SetAppIndexingProvider(new IOSAppIndexingProvider());
#endif
```